# Is it permissible to like gay people? To be friends with them? To perhaps think they are . . . cute?

Tags: homosexuality, evil-thoughts

I am really ashamed asking this, but as a girl growing up boy-girl relationships have always been a no-no. I don't even talk much to guys, unless necessary. Upon encountering romance - TV, movies, books, - I always rolled my eyes because I hated romance, seemed too stupid, dumb to me.

Then I read a book where two guys feel you know in love and I thought it was the first time I did not want to continue to see what happened - I though the mm couple was cute. Now I always think they are cute? I am a girl so naturally I dislike lesbians and stuff, but ....ugh.

I wish I could be disgusted by them but I am addicted, not wholly, to gay books [Only YA stuff, not any uter haram erotic stuff, ew] . I've vowed never again to seek out a gay book but if I see two gay guys, I still think Awww. Please help!

Comment: What is YA stuff. I need to take a look at them before writing a answer.

Comment: This is indeed a remarkable question. I was thinking about this question quite a lot. Hope you get a good answer.

Comment: Would this fall under "reviling the religion"?

Comment: I think this question has been asked befor, could anybody check for the duplicate?

Comment: Its haram to promote homossexuality in any form according to Islam, I think you can be friend with them, and accept them, but if you are obsessed with the topic and you are reading this books to convince yourself that's ok to be gay, it is better to put yourself far from a  considered haram topic which help you to not be driven astray by Shaitan.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't suggest befriending homosexuals but you are still expected to treat them kindly as fellow humans. Regardless of sins committed, a human is still a human and should be treated with fairness and honesty in Islam.